# Simplify if statement: if (legendTitle != null && legendTitle.equals("My house"))

Tags: java, optimization, intellij-14, code-cleanup

I try to commit my code but the code analysis in IntelliJ shows: 'if' statement can be simpolified in this line:

```
if (legendTitle != null && legendTitle.equals("My house"))
```

legendTitle is a String, I wrote `legendTitle != null` because `.equals` in a null Strings is a NullPointerException

Comment: you could easier do that as this: if ( "My house".equals(legendTitle))

Comment: That said, I probably wouldn't bother - the line is fine as is. At least that way it clearly communicates that the null case has been considered.

Comment: If the `legendTitle` is the result of some method call, you could consider changing the return type of that method call to `Optional<String>` and use the appropriate [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) methods, but if it is something local, that would probably be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Also related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/doesnt-if-0-value-do-more-harm-than-good

Comment: Do you even want to support the case that `legendTitle` is `null`? Because if you consider this a bug in your code you should actually trigger the exception on purpose, fail-fast. Otherwise you wont notice the bug. However, in that case prefer `Objects.requireNonNull(legendTitle);`, more expressive.

Comment: often intellij offers auto-refactorings for that stuff, try `alt + return`

Answer (score 6):

You can write `if ("My house".equals(legendTitle))`. "My house" can never be null so you won't get NullPointerException in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `if (Objects.equals(legendTitle, "My house"))`. The `Objects` class will handle `null` values correctly.